# Prevent javascript search function from slowing down browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of javascript / jquery that upon pressing "enter" in a search box goes through all table rows and then hides those which are not applicable/ do not contain the string. This process is however is extremely taxing on slower systems and so I decided to implement a small loading gif so people know something is happening even though it seems the browser has frozen. The problem though is that the image never appears. I'm assuming it's because the browser freezes. So, now to my question. How can i either make the loop faster, use less computing power, and show the gif? Thank you very much

```
var $rows = $('tbody tr.visall');
$('#search').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
        $('.load').show();
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    };
    $('.load').hide();
});
```

edit: this code goes through about 9000-10000 tr elements.

Comment: Might be worth adding a jsFiddle to help with this, quite difficult to try anything without data.  One change I would make is to not use .hide() and .show().  Instead add and remove a 'hide' class and handle any fade in/out with CSS transitions.  This should push the overhead for the animation onto the GPU.

Comment: @PeteAUK I can't really whip up an example that quickly because the code has to go through thousands of rows of data.

Comment: what i think is.. its practically very difficult to achieve this on browser... my suggestion would be to have pagination or the more difficult way would be to filter the "tr" only which are available/seen currently on the viewport(this would be difficult to do)

Comment: Insert the information first in a table in a database then use autocomplete search and pagination.

Comment: With that amount of data you're better off performing this using an AJAX query and limiting the response.  My general rule of thumb is that if a table is more than a couple hundred rows, client side processing is going to be consistently poor.  Is there any specific reason why you wish to do this client side?

Comment: @PeteAUK No, in this case the reason I made it client side is because it was easier to implement at the time.

Comment: The problem of slowness is you are redrawing 10000 `tr`s, which probably have a lot of `td`s within. This is extremely costly operation on its own. You should try to implement a pagination like system so you don't show everything at once. (infinite scroll is a good idea). If you want the search to be faster, keep actual data in a JS object, have a reference to its view (HTML element, or its id). make the calculation and show whatever is necessary. Remember: DOM is freaking slow, try to avoid accessing to it while you can.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say if it will be enough for your data. But here is what you can do:

1. Reduce the amount of dom manipulations. You can add|remove class `hidden` to show hide rows.
2. If your text is static you can create text cache and do not extract it on every search.
3. You can use `setTimeout` to delay search execution to show loading gif. Not even sure you will need one. Searching in memory is quite fast.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xm879/2/).

Code

```
$(function() {
    var table = $('#mytable'), //your table
        rows = table.find('tr').map(function(){ //all rows you need
            return $(this);    
        }),
        rowsCache = (function(from){ //text cache
            return from.map(function(){
                return this.text();
            });
        }(rows));

    function delay(func) { //delayed function executor
        setTimeout(func, 13);
    }

    var load = $('#load'); //your loader

    $('#search').keydown(function(e){
        var val;
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            val = $.trim($(this).val());
            load.show();
            table.hide(); //release dom
            delay(function() {
                //search in text cache
                var toShow = rowsCache.map(function(_, row) { 
                    return row.indexOf(val) > -1;
                }); 

                rows.each(function(i){ 
                     //simply toggle class let css work for you
                     this.toggleClass('hidden', !toShow[i]);  
                });                
                load.hide();
                table.show();
            });
        }
    });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say drop the `filter` and use CSS selectors instead then it's just basic DOM manipulation which jQuery should be optimized for.

See http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ for documentation and here is a little fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tgz5X/

Here is what I use in the fiddle as a simple example

```
function search(mySearchValue) {
    $("tr > td:contains(" + mySearchValue + ")").show();
    $("tr > td:not(:contains(" + mySearchValue + "))").hide();    
}
```

You would need more but you should get the idea behind this approach.

Or use `filter` still but with selectors, also this may trigger `hide` on element which will have `show` after so more DOM manipualtion

```
$("tr td").hide().filter(":contains(" + mySearchValue + ")").show();
```

Comment: Have you tried this with 10k rows? `contains` is not a native selector.

Comment: @gillesc I tried adding rows. I put in about 4k rows and added a row at the bottom that contains the word message. It does not search that quickly and for some reason the "message" td row is at the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/gdLqR/embedded/result/